# Unable to make subsequent subqueries dynamically pick the date as the first subquery in the given SQL code

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```
WITH Months AS (
  SELECT
    TO_CHAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -9, CURRENT_DATE), 'Mon-YYYY') AS StartMonth,
    TO_CHAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -8, CURRENT_DATE), 'Mon-YYYY') AS SecondMonth,
    TO_CHAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -7, CURRENT_DATE), 'Mon-YYYY') AS ThirdMonth
),

ClaimsData AS (
  SELECT
    claim_status_last_updated_date,
    user_id,
    partner_validation_status
  FROM claims_basic
  WHERE TO_CHAR(claim_status_last_updated_date, 'Mon-YYYY') IN ((SELECT StartMonth FROM Months), (SELECT SecondMonth FROM Months), (SELECT ThirdMonth FROM Months))
),

KnownUsers AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    source_user_id
  FROM user_last_activity
  WHERE account_creation_date < DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', DATEADD(MONTH, -9, CURRENT_DATE))
),

Customers AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    source_user_id
  FROM user_last_activity
  WHERE last_partner_validation_status_update_date < DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', DATEADD(MONTH, -9, CURRENT_DATE))
),

QualifiedKnownUsers AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    ku.source_user_id
  FROM KnownUsers ku
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customers cu WHERE cu.source_user_id = ku.source_user_id)
)

SELECT
  TO_CHAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CURRENT_DATE), 'Mon-YYYY') AS Qualifying_Month,
  TO_CHAR(mc.claim_status_last_updated_date, 'Mon-YYYY') AS MonthYear,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN c.source_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS "Customer(Total_Claims)",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN c.source_user_id IS NOT NULL AND mc.partner_validation_status = 'Qualified For Gift' THEN 1 END) AS "Customer(Qualified_for_Gift)",
  NULLIF(CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN c.source_user_id IS NOT NULL AND mc.partner_validation_status = 'Qualified For Gift' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(CASE WHEN c.source_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), 0) AS "Customers_percentage",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ku.source_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS "Known_User(Total_Claims)",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ku.source_user_id IS NOT NULL AND mc.partner_validation_status = 'Qualified For Gift' THEN 1 END) AS "Known_User(Qualified_for_Gift)",
  NULLIF(CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN ku.source_user_id IS NOT NULL AND mc.partner_validation_status = 'Qualified For Gift' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(CASE WHEN ku.source_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), 0) AS "Known_Users_percentage",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN c.source_user_id IS NULL AND ku.source_user_id IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS "Unknown_User(Total_Claims)",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN c.source_user_id IS NULL AND ku.source_user_id IS NULL AND mc.partner_validation_status = 'Qualified For Gift' THEN 1 END) AS "Unknown_User(Qualified_for_Gift)",
  NULLIF(CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN c.source_user_id IS NULL AND ku.source_user_id IS NULL AND mc.partner_validation_status = 'Qualified For Gift' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(CASE WHEN c.source_user_id IS NULL AND ku.source_user_id IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), 0) AS "Unknown_Users_percentage"
FROM ClaimsData mc
LEFT JOIN QualifiedKnownUsers ku ON mc.user_id = ku.source_user_id
LEFT JOIN Customers c ON mc.user_id = c.source_user_id
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(mc.claim_status_last_updated_date, 'Mon-YYYY'), TO_CHAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, mc.claim_status_last_updated_date), 'Mon-YYYY');
```

The code was build with objective that for a given qualified month say 'Jan24' then can we populate the data for different customer groups for May23, Jun23 and Jul23.

Desired Result: In the above code the script should dynamically pick the changing month in subquery for Customers and KnownUsers based on the month which has been picked in the ClaimsData subquery.
I am struggling to make all the three subqueries pick the same month in order.
and secondly the fist subquery ClaimsData picks date in month-year format while the second and third subquery should pick date in first date of the month format '2023-05-01' for comparison

Thanks for helping me in my struggle.

Comment: You have shown a lot of code -- can you help narrow-down the _specific_ problem you are having? For example, all the COUNT and NULLIF stuff down the bottom is not relevant for your question, so perhaps you can simplify it down to the actual parts that are causing you difficulty? Also, can you give us some examples of what is happening that you want to 'fix'? We don't have your database, so it's hard to know what's working and not working for you.

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting? A "Dates" table would probably be a lot more helpful than all the date-to-character string conversions you're doing. Can you provide some sample data, what it looks like when run through your query, and how you're expecting it to look? As written, your question is hard to understand.

Comment: To simplify it 
There are four subqueries in order Months, ClaimsData, KnownUsers and Customers
Months subquery is used to populate three months and the three below subqueries are used to pick data from the table based on populated months in order.
ClaimsData is able to pick right month but I am unable to make KnownUsers and Customers subquery pick the same month which is used by ClaimsData.

Is there a way we can achieve it. Thanks for the help @John Rotenstein

Comment: It's your data. Only you know what it contains. I agree with @digital.aaron -- you should standardise your dates. Preferably always use a Date field and only convert to text when displaying results. Comparing dates like `Mon-YYYY` is bound to cause problems (not to mention it doesn't sort well).

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein for the support. You are right its my data and I should fix it. Finally found the resolution. Cheers!